# How to implement hardware multi-factor authentication on ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, sms, google-authenticator, dongle

Trying to implement multi-factor authentication on my ASP.NET MVC website using the [gemalto hardware dongle](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002CRN5X8) **or something similar**. Can someone point me to the correct direction please?

I googled, but all are talking about using Google Authenticator, but there are employees that don't want to use their own phone for work purpose and refuse to install Google Authenticator on their private phone or receive SMS sign in code, and it is obviously silly for the company to buy each employee a work phone just so that they can use Google Authenticator or receive SMS codes - it is much cheaper to buy a dongle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the best solution is a reprogrammable hardware token. Hardware tokens are devices intended special for generating OTPs. They are typically small and has a form of a key fob or a card. A token is a device that uses an OTP generation algorithm to generate one time passwords when requested by the user. Tokens are a convenient solution as they are stand-alone devices that don't need access to any network. You can find more information about Protectimus solutions following this link: [www.protectimus.com](https://protectimus.com/pricing?utm_source=Stackoverflow&utm_medium=comment&utm_campaign=nov_17)